# Kafka connect Retry operation with Kafka 0.9

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, apache-kafka-connect

I am currently working on implementing a Kafka connect Sink connector from a Kafka 0.9 topic ( I can't upgrade the Kafka version now.)  For exceptions, I could see the Kafka connect retrying. I have some questions on the retry operation. I couldn't find out completely how the Kafka connect retry operation behaves with Kafka 0.9.

1. Is there a limit on the retry after an exception?
2. Where is the retry limit or interval configured for kafka 0.9 ?
3. If there is a retry limit or interval, what will happen once the retry limit is over ?
4. Where can i see the status of a connector task in kafka 0.9.?
5. What would happen to the task at end of retry in 0.9 version?
6. Are there any exclusion on the exceptions where retry is not available?

If there are any good articles covering Kafka Connect for 0.9, please provide pointers.

Comment: What is the sink connector that you are using?

Comment: Sink is from Kafka to Google Pubsub and using CloudPubSubConnector for that.